# Get the line after white-space in C++

Tags: c++, file

I would like to read last few characters in each line of a text file. How would I do that in better optimized C++ code? For example my file has names and ages separated by a white-space of 100 students with new line for each student, so I only want to read the content after white space, i.e age and do further comparison.

```
 File classlist.txt
 Tanya 24
 Max 16
 Dic 21
```

Code I wrote so far

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    ifstream class_details("classlist.txt");
    if (!class_details.is_open())
    {
        cout<< "error"<<'\n';
        return;
    }
    string data;
    % From here I am thinking on how to get the data after first whitespace            
    % in each line
    class_details.close();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Better optimized is relative. What code do you have now?

Comment: @Tanya, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The input operator `>>` separates on white-space.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I knew that point. Even getline() with ' ' as delimiter separates on white-space. But I was thinking if I can read a line from the end until first white space.

Comment: I/O is costly.  You cannot save the "cost" of reading the name, as all the characters must be inspected anyway to find the whitespace.  Just do the obvious readable thing: read the name and age, store them in a data structure, and move on.

Comment: @Peter, while you cannot save the "cost" of the I/O, you could save the cost of building a `std:string` from a series of extracted characters, which is subsequently discarded.   `class_details.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ' ');` would extract and ignore everything up to and including the first space (`\x20`) character.

Answer (score 3):

As @Joachim notes, the input operator `>>` separates on white-space.

You can use it as follows:

```
string name;
int age;
while (class_details >> name >> age) {
   // Use name & age here.
}
```

`class_details >> name` extracts a word (non-white-space characters) from the input stream, and stores it in the `name` variable, and returns the original stream object `class_details`.  This allows chaining the input extraction ...

(Since `class_details >> name`, returns `class_details`, we can further apply the `>>` to the return value of the expression to extract more information.)

`>> age` continues the extraction, reading (since `age` is an integer variable) an integer from the input stream, and storing it in the `age` variable, and (continuing the chain) returns the original stream object `class_details`.

The expression in the `while(...)` loop returns (due to the way the `>>` operators allows chaining) the original input stream, which when evaluated in `boolean` context, returns the stream's `good()` state.  If the end of stream has been encountered, or an invalid extraction was attempted, or any other problem, `good()` would return `false`, and exit the loop.

So, without chaining (but using the `,` operator instead), the above could be rewritten more verbosely as:

```
string name;
int age;
while(class_details >> name, class_details >> age, class_details.good()) {
    // Use name & age here.
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If the goal is to ignore the name field (skip the name without extracting it into a variable), you could use the [`ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) method to skip everything up to the next ***space character***:

```
int age;
while (class_details.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ' ') >> age >> ws) {
   // Use age here.
}
```

The `>> ws` is being used to consume any white-space from the end of the "age" field to the beginning of the name field on the next line ... specifically, the "new line" character.

You can use number smaller than `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`, if desired.  Just choose something longer than your longest name.

Answer (score 0):

With my less knowleage

1 : copy data every time to compare if same break

```
    while(1)
    {

    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), f); // scanf what you want

    if( strcmp(str1,str2)==0 )break;

    strcpy(str2,str1);

    }
```

2 : at last add some thing weird

```
    while(1)
    {

    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), f); // scanf what you want

    if( str1 == "key" )break;

    }
```